# Post-apocalyptic novel from the 80s about survivors travelling in a land train across America

Tags: story-identification, books, post-apocalyptic

I need help finding a book (I read in the 80s):

Post-apocalyptic novel about a group of survivors in some kind of land train traveling across America.
The leaders keep people inside all the time, due to radioactive wasteland, but, the big reveal is that the world has recovered, but they lie about it to control the passengers.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Do you happen to remember anything about the cover art?  Was it a standalone book or part of a series?

Comment: I ask if it's part of a series because Patrick Tilley's *Amtrak Wars* (published in the mid-80s) has the underground society ("Amtrak Federation") deploying land trains as part of the campaign to "retake" the surface.  The cover of the second book, [*First Family*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1746518.First_Family), shows one.

Comment: {nods} Although I think that that one still has the outside as a wasteland (as seen by the protagonist, who helps defend against the "savages"), but one which is being recovered.

Comment: This does sound very familiar... although it is a common trope of "we're faking the disaster to keep everyone underground and not damaging the Earth again".

Comment: Perhaps "Cloud Warriors", by Patrick Tilley? This novel is part of a series. The protagonist is an ultralight aircraft pilot who is captured by the mutant aborigines who live on the surface, and he lives among them.